# Assigning variable while clicking on an ipywidgets button. button.on_click event

Tags: python, python-3.x, jupyter-notebook, ipywidgets

I'm trying to code a simple app that takes all the xml files from the folder, and then scraps all the needed from the files. I wanted to make the program usable for those who can not code in python.

I want to run the files_in_folder_path function after applicable button is clicked, and store the values returned by files_in_folder_path in variables.

and there is the problem, i can not find a way to assign the returned values to the variables(i will need these variables later in program) when the function is being run with a button.

There is the files_in_folder_path func:

```py
def files_in_folder_path(b):

    folder_path = filedialog.askdirectory()
    files_in_folder = [f for f in listdir(folder_path) if isfile(join(folder_path, f))]
    return files_in_folder,folder_path
```

and there is how i try to run it

```py
button_path = widgets.Button(description="Click Me!")
display(button_path)
button_path.on_click(files_in_folder_path)
```

is there any way to store the values returned by files_in_folder_path in a variables while the function is being triggered with the button?

Regards!

Comment: You could try assigning the value to the button instance, with `b.files_in_folder = files_in_folder` in your `files_in_folder_path` function, and then access the variable later on in your code.

Answer (score 0):

For future comers, create the variable in the parent scope and assign it from within the function. The gotcha is an issue with ipywidgets when the variable is not a dict. Check https://github.com/jupyter-widgets/ipywidgets/issues/3292

Here's the working sample from the issue

```
import ipywidgets as widgets

x = 0
y = {"x": 0}
b = widgets.Button(description="Do it")

def doit(obj):
    print(x, y)
    # x += 1 # uncommenting makes the above print fail
    y["x"] += 1 # this is ok

b.on_click(doit)
display(b)
```